# How to use 'apply ... with' and 'apply ... in' together?

Tags: coq

I know that `apply f in H` can be used to apply a hypothesis to a function, and I know that `apply f with a b c` can be used to supply the arguments it cannot infer on its own while applying `f` directly.

Would it be possible to use the two combined somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the reference manual: https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.apply-in.

You can use `apply f with ... in h` with a binding list

```
apply f with (x := u) (0 := v) in h
```

but it seems that the version with just terms is reserved to `apply`.
This is a bit heavier but should be able to get the same results.